# How to add space between chart and tick labels?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, victory-charts

Trying to get a sense for how [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) works. Out of the box, I noticed that there's no spacing between the "tick labels" and the [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHe8x.png). You can see I tried to manually change label position but the position styles aren't being applied. It's strange because in all the examples on their docs there seems to be space. Here's my [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880fv.png).
Seems like an issue that shouldn't be very hard to figure out, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `tick labels` here is yAxis value ( `$20k`, `$15k`, ..etc) ?
My workaround solution is adding one or two space in the end of the value like `20k`

Answer (score 0):

You can add tickLabelComponent

`tickLabelComponent={<VictoryLabel dx={-6} dy={-6}/>}`

in the Victoryaxis component to change the style of tick labels of a particular axis.